# Windows.Web.HttpClient: Cookies will not be sent

Tags: cookies, httpclient

I send a HTTP Get Request with a Basic Authentification to the Login-Endpoint of the Host:

```
            request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            // Configuration Item: Login URL Suffix
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/{1}", Host, loginSuffix));
            request.Method = Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Get;

            var info = User + ":" + Password;
            var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(info));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Basic", token);

            _httpClient = CreateHttpClient(ref cookieManager);
            response = await _httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The HttpClient is created with a Filter, to set Cookies later:

```
    private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(ref HttpCookieManager _cookieManager)
    {
        HttpBaseProtocolFilter _filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();

        HttpClient _httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(_filter);

        _cookieManager = _filter.CookieManager;

        return _httpClient;
    }
```

From the Response the SET-COOKIE Header can be read.

```
        string[] Queries;
        response.Headers.TryGetValue("Set-Cookie", out tmpString);
        if (tmpString != null)
            Queries = tmpString.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I´m looking for a Cookie with a defined Name (CookieKeyName), which will be set in the next Request.

```
        foreach (var query in Queries)
        {
            if (query.Contains(CookieKeyName))
            {
                staticCookieKey = query.Substring(0, query.IndexOf("="));
                staticCookieValue = query.Substring(query.IndexOf("=") + 1);
            }
        }
```

I would expect, that the HttpClient will use the received Set-Cookie in the response for this URL as Cookie in every following Request automatically.

I´m preparing the next Request and setting the Cookie by myself:

```
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/qcbin", Host));
            request.Method = Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Get;

            HttpCookie _cookie = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpCookie(staticCookieKey, Host, "/");
            _cookie.Value = staticCookieValue;
            bool replaced = cookieManager.SetCookie(_cookie);
```

The following Sending of the Requests provides to a Web Exception 401, because the Server expects for this URL the previously in the Response received Cookie.

```
            response = await _httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Looking with Fiddler on the Line, the second Request contains no Cookie Header. Even Setting of the Cookie in CookieManager nor the proceeding of the Set-Cookie i the first Response by the HttpClient is working.

Hint: The length of the value of the Cookies is about 6000 chars (coming from a IBM Data Power).

Thank you in advance for help.